# recurrence relation of Gaussian distribution derivation $a_{n+2} = \mu a_{n+1} + \sigma^2(n+1)a_n $

Tags: calculus, probability

I have come across a question that asks to derive below recurrence relation (where $a_n = E[X^n]$) of the higher moments of Gaussian distribution, however I have tried integration by parts as suggested but I can't find the trick to solve it somehow, it's been bothering me for 2 days already, can anyone enlighten me please.
$$a_{n+2} = \mu a_{n+1} + \sigma^2(n+1)a_n $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts, whereby

$\int u.dv=uv-\int v.du$

the trick is to include the exponential term as the $dv$ component and exploit the identity

$\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}e^{f(x)}$

We have the following (adding and subtracting $\mu$ and multiplying and dividing by $\sigma^2$ (see $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ terms below) will lead to a nice expression when differentiating the exponential term for integration by parts)
\begin{align}
a_{n+2} &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x^{n+2}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx\\
&= \frac{\color{red}{\sigma^2}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x^{n+1}\left(\frac{x\color{red}{+\mu-\mu}}{\color{red}{\sigma^2}}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx\\
&= \color{blue}{\frac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x^{n+1}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx} + \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x^{n+1}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx\\
&=\color{blue}{\mu a_{n+1}} + \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x^{n+1}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx
\end{align}
Now we can apply integration by parts to the second term of the RHS by setting
\begin{align}
u = x^{n+1} &\Rightarrow du = (n+1)x^n\\
dv = \frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) &\Rightarrow v=-\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{align}
resulting in
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int x^{n+1}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx &= \sigma^2\require{cancel}\cancel{\left[-\frac{x^{n+1}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}}\\&+\frac{\sigma^2(n+1)}{\color{green}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}}\color{green}{\int x^n\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx}\\
&=0+\sigma^2(n+1)\color{green}{a_n}
\end{align}
Combining the two terms leads to the desired recurrence.

Comment: Thank you so much Alijah for your time and detailed explanation, really appreciate it.